# How do I open WordPad with predefined text (like a template)?

Tags: windows, templates, wordpad

I'd like WordPad to open from, say, a desktop shortcut with a predefined text inserted.

It should create a new document and not open an existing one, the function should be the same as in a Word template.

The existing command line options do not allow for that, is there a workaround?

Comment: cp template.rtf new.rtf && wordpad new.rtf

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified which Windows you are on, so I am telling about My Windows 8.1

create your template and save it as an rtf file in some folder, say E:\MyData\wordpad\template.rtf

Open Windows Explorer, right click on the name of any rtf file, select open with, then assign rtf to be opened with Wordpad, also tick "always use this program to open this type of file" or whatever it says.

or

you can do the same through Control Panel - Default Programs, assign .rtf to be opened with wordpad.

Go to Start - metro interface.

look for wordpad and rightclick on its tile

or if it is not appearing, type wordpad, so it appears, rightclick on Wordpad name

Click open file location.

That will open the shortcut that windows installs for Wordpad.

Right Click on the shortcut, click properties

there "%ProgramFiles%\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe" should be appearing.

add a space and E:\MyData\wordpad\template.rtf after that so that it appears fully as

This was the location where you had saved your template in Step 1 above.

"%ProgramFiles%\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe" E:\MyData\wordpad\template.rtf

click Apply or OK and Exit.

Now whenever you run Wordpad from anywhere, your template.rtf will open as a default.